# Qgis-Web-Client - Windows - Red Screen

Tags: qgis, windows, server

Well, I'm a Windows user and a newbie with Web mapping technology, but I've had success with qgis server and the "getmap" and "getcapabilities" work well.

Now I'm trying to have the same success with Qgis Web Client, but appeared a little problem: The metadata, legend and layers appear, but the map is not showing up (instead appears a red broken layer). What could be the problem?

[image: windows - Qgis web client]

I don't know, but maybe I could have done something wrong in files like qgis-web-client.conf, or globaloptions.js, so i'll show you screenshots of it.

Qgis-web-client.conf:
[image: Qgis-web-client.conf]

GlobalOptions.Js:

http://jsfiddle.net/nYfLZ/

[image: GlobalOptions.Js]
[image: GlobalOptions.Js]
[image: GlobalOptions.Js]
[image: GlobalOptions.Js]

Or, do I need to edit GISProjectListing.js ?

http://jsfiddle.net/rWV7v/

GISProjectListing.js Screenshot:
[image: GISProjectListing.js]

Or it could be something else?
[image: Qgis]

Comment: can you place your javascript code on jsfiddle - it is much easier to read and debug.

Comment: post edited with jsfiddle links